# How do I know current status of Aged Away flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, flag-history

I'm looking at my Aged Away Post flags and see that

- a few are removed, probably by script (*Won't the script consider pending flags as helpful?*)  [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208135/client-server-system-based-on-aws-architecture)
- a few are closed (*It may be because someone raised flag after my flag got expired?*) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509576/how-to-remove-select-in-grid-view)
- a few are re-flagged by me but this doesn't reflect here! [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37860259/multidimensional-associative-arrays-in-korn-shell)

It is a little bit confusing for me to go back, verify and re-flag, if necessary.  What is the real expectations of flagging system?

- You raise flag once and forget, whatsoever the status?

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592353/how-to-take-a-picture-in-a-webpage-using-pc-mobile-camera-without-3rd-party-libr) is not a question and is eligible for removal.  My flag is aged-away and the question is still alive on SO. *I'm not allowed to re-flag!! Strange!!* (EDIT: I flagged thiss question in chat room, and it is handled but my flag status doesn't reflect any change; nor I do see latest question status until I open it)

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857856/returning-an-identity-after-insert-then-using-identity-value-in-another-insert) is a real duplicate and it is still pending review.  Meanwhile, someone answered, got acceptance and then the rep :).  I know my flag will eventually *age away*.  Is it because we have more flags than that can be handled by our current mods / reviewers?

Can we enhance [aged away screen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/2169261?group=1&status=5) to reflect the current status of the question, so as to quickly see if we need to re-flag?  I'm not sure if I'm asking the correct questions, but it is kind of convoluted process!!

Comment: As a comment, Example 2 was never aged away. You only cast one flag on that, and the flag was marked as helpful upon completion of the close votes review.

Comment: @BradLarson you are right; I need to re-search  my history, It seems I incorrectly linked Example 2

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's quite clear what the current status of your aged away flags are:

> [image: one says closed, the other is red and deleted]

One of those was closed. The other was deleted (by Roomba).

(Note that the one that got closed was not as a result of my flag. You don't get any reward for being a month ahead of the game (after your flag ages away). However, I think I may still have indirectly contributed to its closing, with my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280085/323179).)

I assume that "the script" you refer to is the Roomba. Roomba does not close questions when it deletes them (some may already be closed). I don't think that it marks anything as helpful, since getting auto-deleted is not necessarily a sign that a question is off-topic. It only means that the question was unpopular (lack of answers/views) and down voted.

I suspect that the flag aged away while the question was at 0 score. One of the most effective ways I have found of "cleaning up" my aged away flag history is to go back and see what's eligible for Roomba, and seeing what I can down vote to push under the threshold for automatic deletion.

If you look at how many things are in the close vote queue, you'll see why so many flags age away. You should see about getting that last 1k rep so you can try and help us cut it down. I actually haven't had many flags (if any) age away since my close flags became close votes.

Comment: *You don't get any reward for being a month ahead of the game*.. Something I disagree; it appears that the game started late on that question.  You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592353/how-to-take-a-picture-in-a-webpage-using-pc-mobile-camera-without-3rd-party-libr)

Comment: `It only means that the question was unpopular (lack of answers/views) and down voted.` I believe it may be still appropriate to either mark some other status on question; or delete the aged-away flag altogether; it is not useful anymore to be on aged-away; or mark some other status on flag (other than helpful/declined/disputed); I somehow feel it will be good to do something with aged-away or pending flags when Roomba deletes a question;

Comment: @techspider Those with 10k+rep can see why a question was deleted. By the way, I agree that it would be useful to be able to filter out those "unactionable" flags. There is a request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264172/323179) that may be of interest.